# Energy for a Lattice gas model

Tags: field-theory, phase-transition, ising-model

The energy for a Lattice gas model can be written as
\begin{equation}
E_{LG} = \frac{\epsilon}{4} \sum_{<i,j>} (s_{ij} + s_i +s_j +1) - \frac{\mu}{2}\sum_i (s_i +1) \\
= \frac{\epsilon}{4} \sum_{<i,j>} s_i s_j- \frac{q \epsilon}{4}\sum_is_{i}- \frac{\mu}{2}\sum_i s_i + \text{constants}
\end{equation}

where $q$ is the nearest neighbour

Where does $\frac{q \epsilon}{4}\sum_is_{i}$ come from? and what happens to the $s_j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To each edge $\langle i,j\rangle$, your first sum associates $\sigma_i+\sigma_j$. In particular, the term $\sigma_k$ appears once for each edge having $k$ as an endpoint. The number of such edges is equal to the number of neighbors of $k$, which is $q$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}(\sigma_i+\sigma_j) = q \sum_i \sigma_i.
$$
Alternatively, in a more formal way,
\begin{align}
\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}(\sigma_i+\sigma_j)
&= \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\sigma_i + \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\sigma_j \\
&= \tfrac12 \sum_i\sum_{j\sim i} \sigma_i + \tfrac12 \sum_j\sum_{i\sim j} \sigma_j \\
&= \sum_i\sum_{j\sim i} \sigma_i \\
&= \sum_i \sigma_i \underbrace{\sum_{j\sim i} 1}_{=q} \\
&= q \sum_i \sigma_i,
\end{align}
where the notation $\sum_{j\sim i}$ means that the sum is restricted to the neighbors $j$ of the vertex $i$.
(The factors $\frac12$ in the second line come from the fact that summing first over $i$ and then over its neighbor $j$ will yields each edge twice (once for each ordering of the two endpoints); the third line follows from the fact that both sums are equal.)